# Is it possible to have a bounded continuous function f:(a,b) to R such that the derivative of f tends to infinite as we approach b?

Tags: real-analysis

CLAIM:Is not possible to have a bounded differentiable function f:[a,b) to R such that it's derivative  tends to infinite as we approach b. Is the claim correct? How can i prove it? I tried the following proof.Suppose for a contradiction that the claim is wrong. Then such a function f exist. Then i can define a function F[a.b] to R such that F=f in [a,b) but F(b)=limit f(x) as x tends to b. Then F is still differentiable (due to continuoity) and so is derivative at b should be defined so it's not infinite. Contradiction since derivative of F at b is same as derivative of f as x tends to b(due to continuity).

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ can be easily adapted.

Comment: cheers...i should have thought it:D. But what is wrong with the proof?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Look at $\sqrt{1-x}$ over a suitable interval.

Comment: cheers.. but what is wrong with the proof?

Comment: You are assuming that (left) derivatives are continuous. That is false.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Look at $f(x)=\sin\frac1{b-x}$. For this $\lim_{x\to b}f'(x)$ does not exist at all, not even as divergence to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The upper half of a circle is bounded, continuous, and has a tangent line of every possible slope (including $-\infty$ and $\infty$).